# Postgres functions not persisted after db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have created a migration with custom postgres function creation:

```
class CreatePopularityPgFunctions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute %{
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION popularity(count integer, weight integer default 3) RETURNS integer AS $$
        SELECT count * weight
      $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
    }
  end

  def down
    execute 'drop function popularity(integer, integer) cascade'
  end
end
```

and running `rake db:migrate` properly adds it to the schema. However, running `rake db:reset` seems to not create this function in PG for some reason. The function is not in the schema and trying to use it in SQL query results in error about missing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db:reset` runs a `db:drop db:setup`. In `db:setup` creates a database schema. But `schema.rb` doesn't handle a custom functions or views.

From documentation:

> db/schema.rb cannot express database specific items such as foreign key constraints, triggers, or stored procedures. While in a migration you can execute custom SQL statements, the schema dumper cannot reconstitute those statements from the database. If you are using features like this, then you should set the schema format to :sql.

You can use `structure.sql` instead. To use `structure.sql`:

> This is set in config/application.rb by the config.active_record.schema_format setting, which may be either :sql or :ruby.

More details [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps)